# Gunicorn Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Tags: user-permissions, gunicorn

This is my gunicorn config file, with username specification:

`$ cat /etc/gunicorn.d/wsgi.work
CONFIG = {
  'working_dir': '/home/ubuntu/workdir',
  'user' : 'ubuntu',
  'group' : 'ubuntu',
  'args': (
      '--debug',
      '--bind=0.0.0.0:5000',
      '--workers=16',
      '--timeout=60',
      'wsgi:app',
  ),
}
$ sudo service gunicorn restart`

I have this error :

> SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Ubuntu user is the dialout group, so he have acces to /dev/ttyUSB0

Gunicorn run with ubuntu username:

`$ ps aux | grep gunicorn
 ubuntu    2586  0.0  0.5  18024 10824 ?        S    08:54   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn --pid /var/run/gunicorn/wsgi.work.pid --name wsgi.work --user ubuntu --group ubuntu --daemon --log-file /var/log/gunicorn/wsgi.work.log --debug --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --workers=16 --timeout=60 wsgi:app`

And I have check in python code to display username, and it's ok. But running from command line work:

> gunicorn --debug --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app

On Ubuntu 14 Arm Jetson TK1

Comment: What are the permissions of `/dev/ttyUSB0`?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider 660, acces is ok on command line with the user